# SIM is missing and SIM hot swap is configured, but ports are not opened

Tags: intel

Tablet: Dell Venue-11-Pro-7130-vPro
Kernel: Linux version 5.8.0-43
BIOS: A28
RAM: 3840 MB

I get this message in the output but I don't have a sim card, not even a sim card slot.

```
ModemManager[824]: <error> SIM is missing and SIM hot swap is configured, but ports are not opened.
```

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a network problem on that machine, or is it just that message?

If it's just the message, this is most likely nothing to worry about. It is entirely possible that the mainboard has all the hardware for mobile network, but they just didn't connect that chip to the outside and didn't provide a SIM card slot. Hardware makers do that to offer multiple models that can be sold at different prices, yet don't have to develop and maintain actual different hardware.

Comment: No, there are no problems at all, except for a randomly working touchpad. Very fast and stable Rom for me. But I don't like red letters in a magazine.

Comment: If you want a super-tidy system without error messages and you know that you are not using ModemManager because you don't have any related hardware, I guess you can disable it: `sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service`. Check with `sudo systemctl status ModemManager.service`; re-enable with `sudo systemctl enable ModemManager.service`.

Comment: `Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)`  Thanks, but the line in the log is still there ) `SIM is missing and SIM hot swap is configured, but ports are not opened.`

Comment: That message is still there during reboot even with the service disabled? Use `journalctl -b` to only see the messages since the last boot.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted the device, I have it here... in red letters: `journalctl -b-1 -g error`...`ModemManager[789]: <error> SIM is missing and SIM hot swap is configured, but ports are not opened.`

Comment: Hm - it might be using a snap on 20.04. In that case, it might come down to removing that snap which sounds a bit drastic to me.

Comment: If I had a snap-in, I would have solved the problem of a chaotic touchpad connection long ago and  not bothered myself and others with error messages. I'm new to Ubuntu, I haven't even used it for a month.

Comment: No, I meant a snap package.